# For Android ASOP, is 'repo sync' actually download the whole source code tree event if I use a -b argument to specify a branch

Tags: android, git, version-control, android-source

If I use `repo -u init [url] -b gingerbread` and executed `epo sync`, is only the source code of ginerbread is downloaded? As I know, git will actually keep the whole repository. So I suppose if I can do something like `git checkout ics` to get the ICS source code event I only executed `repo -u [url] -b gingerbread`.

I am not quite understand how `repo` command works.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the single branch use the -c argument.  It's also faster and less space will probably be used.

repo sync -c ...